# Angular5-Pass value of index to component

Tags: angular

How should I pass the value of index of the option selected to the component.

```
<select (click)= "onpressed(i)" placeholder="select a value" class="custom-select"  >
<option *ngFor="let data of data3; let i = index;"   value = {{data.dash_name}} >
{{data.dash_name}}
 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Post a clear and complete question, and post the relevant code in the question itself, as properly formatted text. Not as a link to an image.

Comment: I have edited my question. @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this.

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.selectedIndex)">
<option  *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;" [value]="item.value">{{item.value}}</option>
```

**Component:**

```
onChange(index){
  console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: The value of index obtained in console is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

[Live Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-u1ow9s)  Relevant code in in files modalTest.component.ts and app.component.html

Try this:

```
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="index">
  <option *ngFor="let razon of razones; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">
    {{razon.descRazon}}
  </option>
</select>
```

In the component class

```
export class ModalTest  {

    razones = [{
      descRazon:'testing Uno'
    },{
      descRazon:'testing Dos'
    }]

    index = 0;

  constructor(){}

}
```